# Wall mounting to 300 (w) x 200 (h) VESA specifications

Tags: mounting, television

I'm trying to mount my new LG C7 which has VESA 300 (w) x 200 (h).

I purchased this wall mount which clearly states it is compatible with said VESA mount.

https://www.invisiontvbrackets.com/invisionr-tv-wall-bracket-mount-double-arm-tilt-swivel-24-55-hdtv-dl

However I cannot find any arrangement of the arms in which I can achieve this. I can get the width but not the height, or the height but not the width - never both.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

The diagram attached will help someone cleverer than I figure this out hopefully. [image]

Comment: Are you seeing and taking advantage of the full adjustability of  the arms. Can you see the swing in the arms.

Comment: The arms don't actually swing, each arm is able to be mounted in one of two positions on each corner. I managed to get it working simply by losing two of the arms - not sure how orthodox this is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the company directly - for anyone who has this issue in future it requires this configuration:

[image]

Comment: That's the conclusion I drew based on the dimensions shown in the drawing provided. Was the mistake in assuming that only the end holes in each arm were to be used?